# Google Admob in Windows 8.1 app

Tags: admob, windows-8.1

Is Google Admob available for windows 8.1 apps?,If it is how to enable them in windows 8.1 applications?

Comment: No it isn't. Currently, Google Admob is only available on windows phone 8, android and ios

Comment: Any other except adDuplex and PubCenter?

Comment: There are about 4 more. Check out my answer

Answer (score 8):

Currently, Google Admob is only available on windows phone 8, android and ios.

I believe Google Admob and other ad providers will make their SDKs for Windows 8 apps once the platform gets more success.

Until then, you can either use one or a combination of the following:

```
Microsoft PubCenter

Ad Duplex

Leadbolt

scoreoid

Mediabrix
```

More [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/uk_faculty_connection/archive/2014/04/07/adding-ads-into-apps-and-games.aspx)

You can also use [AdRotator](http://wp7adrotator.codeplex.com/) to achieve a +99% fill rate by real time swapping/replacing of ad providers.