# Can we add google admob in WP8.1 WinRT App

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to add google ad mob in wp8.1 WinRT app but facing some issues like 
can anybody help me such as why we are unable to use google admob in WP8.1 WnRT app. And how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

For your convenience (and their money) Microsoft wants you to use [PubCenter](http://PubCenter.Microsoft.Com/). You can see more data on how to use the advertising SDK Made by them for use of PubCenter [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/advertising-windows-sdk%28v=msads.10%29.aspx)

Comment: Very very thank u so much for your suggetion but i want to know can we use Google AdMob in WP8.1 like as WP8.0 if no than can you elaborate why?
  Please

Comment: I am pretty sure it is impossible but I'm not 100% sure

Answer (score 0):

You can't use Google AdMob in Windows Phone 8.1 Store Application (or Windows Store Apps).
You can use Google AdMob only for Windows Phone Silverlight Apps (8.0 or 8.1)

Comment: Thanks for that but  when my app was targeting WP8.1 than google ad mob was working fine and if when i targeted my same app on WP8.1 Silverlight than "ads no fill error" start to occur on ad Failed event.

Comment: it's strange because google admob contains some namespaces which unavailable for WP8.1 Store Apps

[link to other topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25466448/google-admob-in-windows-8-1-app)